# windbg log system calls

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I want to log all system calls from winlogon.exe. I have already setup up connection between WinDbg on the host computer and kernel debugger in virtual machine, and every thing work perfect, except one thing - I cannot load logexts extension, which can be used to log all system calls. The problem is when I am trying to load logexts, I get a error:

```
> .load logexts
The call to LoadLibrary(logexts) failed with error 2.
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access
```

I tried to debug notepad.exe, and this extension worked perfectly, so I think problem not in debugger itself. My question is can I log system calls in WinDbg by myself, without any additional libs, such as logexts?

Comment: [Error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx) 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. So maybe you should check your debugger's configuration after all.

Comment: dont remember offhand but logger.exe and logexts are both meant for usermode debugging not kernelmode (iirc it hooks and detours kernel32.dll in usermode to wrap function calls)

Comment: Are you using the instructions in section "Debugging WinLogon" in the debugger help file? If so, are you attempting to load the logexts extension from ntsd or kd? If kd, try loading from ntsd.

Comment: @MarcSheman I am trying to load logexts from windbg, connected to the ntsd in my virtual machine.

Comment: Do you load logexts when in the kernel mode debugger (kd) or when in the user mode debugger (ntsd)?

Answer (score 2):

Logexts is an extension for user mode and does not work in kernel mode. From WinDbg help:

> One way to activate Logger is to start CDB or WinDbg and attach to a **user-mode** target application as usual. Then, use the !logexts.logi or !logexts.loge extension command.

(emphasis mine) and also

> [...] that loads and initializes Logexts.dll in the target **application process**.

WinDbg's help does not mention "kernel" anywhere near logexts.dll.

Comment: [Winlogon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541428.aspx) is a **user-mode** system support process.

Comment: @IInspectable: OP says "I have already setup up [...] kernel debugger in virtual machine" IMHO he's trying to trace Winlogon calls from a kernel session.

Comment: If OP is using the instructions in section "Debugging WinLogon" in the debugger help file, then it's not clear if he's attempting to load the extension from the user mode debugger (ntsd) or the kernel mode debugger.

Comment: @MarcSherman I used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541428(v=vs.85).aspx) page to setup debuger. As I understand, I have to set up kernel debugger via editing registry and control it from user mode debugger on my host machine. Is there are any other may to debug winlogon?

Comment: That page describes the recommend way.